# Getting bool values from object

Tags: javascript

I have a an object which is like:

```
var packages = { SoftwareColumn: false, BatchNumberColumn : false, MatrixId : 1, CommentsColumn : true, PartNumber : "Abc123" }
```

The above object is alot larger but for this question I've narrowed it down. What I am trying to achieve if loop over it and get all the key's/values where the value is `true`. I've tried

```
if (packages.length > 0) {
     Object.keys(packages).forEach(function (key) {
        //here I can't figure out how to get values which are only true and get their key
  });
}
```

Comment: If you just want the value of each key -> `return packages[key];`

Comment: Do you also want keys that are "truthy" e.g. Boolean("Abc1234") = true or only values that are actually true?

Comment: @SteffenSchmitz Only the values that are actually true

Comment: Oh. You can filter them first `Object.keys(packages).filter(k => packages[k] == true).forEach(k => console.log(packages[k]))`?

Comment: Object literals do not have the length property as is being tested for in the if statement: `packages.length > 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` instead of `forEach()` loop and return obj. To just return `true` values you can use identity / strict equality `===` operator.

```js
var packages = {
  SoftwareColumn: false,
  BatchNumberColumn: false,
  MatrixId: 1,
  CommentsColumn: true,
  PartNumber: 'Abc123'
}

var newObj = Object.keys(packages).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if(packages[e] === true) r[e] = packages[e]
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! how would I change this to get only the key which has the value true

Comment: You would use array as accumulator in reduce and if value is `true` you push key to that array https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1934/

Comment: Thanks! that's perfect

Comment: Or in that case you can just use filter https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1935/

Answer (score 0):

Objects don't have a length property. This means you will always get undefined in your if.

Using [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) will make checking keys easy:

```js
var packages = { SoftwareColumn: false, BatchNumberColumn : false, MatrixId : 1, CommentsColumn : true, PartNumber : "Abc123" }
var keys = [];

for (key in packages) {
  if (packages[key] === true) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
}


console.log(keys);
```

Comment: (Remember to filter inherited properties and methods)

Answer (score 0):

```
var packages = { SoftwareColumn: false, BatchNumberColumn : false, MatrixId : 1, CommentsColumn : true, PartNumber : "Abc123" }
console.log(packages);
if (Object.keys(packages).length > 0) {
     Object.keys(packages).forEach(function (key) {
            if(packages[key]==true){
          console.log(key);
          }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with [`Array#filter()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjcmbT69IrUAhVMu48KHUgfC8wQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter&usg=AFQjCNHgB7IyOa22NG7kCsGZ1ldwMUmkiA) and [`Array#reduce`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwja7ZWF9YrUAhWLuI8KHTFTBsAQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Freduce&usg=AFQjCNHHMuqxJ882tP03jasOvA3-26VV9Q) .Try with `===` is match the type also .explanation added with comment

```js
var packages = { SoftwareColumn: false, BatchNumberColumn: false, MatrixId: 1, CommentsColumn: true, PartNumber: "Abc123" }

var res = Object.keys(packages).filter(function(a) { // filter the true value keys
  return packages[a] === true //its validate the type of also boolean and true
}).reduce(function(a, b) { //reduce used for recreate the filter object
  a[b] = packages[b] 
  return a
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

For more simplify format with `Arrow function`

```
console.log(Object.keys(packages).filter(a=> (packages[a])).reduce((a,b)=> (a[b] = packages[b] ,a),{}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter and use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for a new objecz

```js
var packages = { SoftwareColumn: false, BatchNumberColumn: false, MatrixId: 1, CommentsColumn: true, PartNumber: "Abc123" },
    trueItems = Object.assign(...Object
        .keys(packages)
        .filter(k => packages[k] === true)
        .map(k => ({ [k]: packages[k] }))
    );
    
console.log(trueItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you would like to only retrieve items which are of type 'Boolean', not "truthy" in terms of JavaScript rules. To verify whether given object's field is boolean, I suggest using either 'typeof' operator or calling Object.prototype.toString.call on object's field ( Myself, I prefer to use second options due to better flexibility, albeit at performance's cost )

```
let packages = { SoftwareColumn: false, BatchNumberColumn : false, MatrixId : 1, CommentsColumn : true, PartNumber : "Abc123" }
let filtered = Object.keys(packages).reduce((acc, key) => {
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(packages[key]) === '[object Boolean]' && packages[key]) {
    acc[key] = packages[key];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```